Does the simplification of 還 to 还 rely on the upper-right 睘?
Does the simplification of 還 to 还 rely on a simplification of the upper-right 睘 in some way? I assume not, as 睘 is not itself simplified (I presume it would be 不 plus something to differentiate it from 不)

I 'don't think so, as "褱 in "壞" and "懷" (坏,怀) were also replaced by "不" in simplification.

There's a rough heuristic you can rely on when determining whether a something is "simplified" (stroke-omitted): Does 还 sound like 不, or mean anything similar to 不? If not, then 不 is the rough outline of a cursive scribble. Here, 不 is indeed a rough outline of 睘, if you do a google image search of 還 草書.

According to zdic, a likely theory is that the two characters originally existed side by side with distinct pronunciations and meanings. Eventually and long before modern day they combined to be interchangable, and eventually each were chosen as a different standardized "spelling" in the modern day.
direct zdic quote:  (1) (形声。从土，褱( huái)声。古代建筑物主要以土建造，故从“土”。本义:倒塌(指建筑物遭到破坏)。按:古代“坏”与“壞”是音义都不相同的两个字。“坏”，本读作 pēi，是个从土、不声的形声字，指“未烧过的砖瓦、陶器”。现在“壞”简化为“坏”)
Regardless this cannot be considered a true simplification like some modern characters are, it falls in the far larger category of just alternate "spellings" or fonts that make up most standard simplified chinese :)


https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1h14y1E7dr

See 0：12, the whole evolving process.
It seems that it's just replaced by another character 不 for no good reason, but at least such writing has been present since Dynasty Qing.
